# Determine the equation for \$v(t)\$

Tags: circuit-analysis

Yes, this is a problem given in class. I'm studying for a test and coudn't find an expression to (). For me it seems like there is not enough data to do that. Can someone give me a direction?

A power supply **V1** is connected to a load **ZL** by a wire of impedance **6,4 + j4,8 Ω**, as shown in the following picture. Knowing that the angular frequency of the supply is **200 rad/s**, the voltage on the load is **100 V (rms)** and that it absorves **1000 W** with a power factor of **0.8**, determine:

(a) The voltage expression for the power supply ();

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Did you try and find the currrent, you know with V = IR or \$ \frac{V_L}{I_L} = Z_L \$ and P = I^2*Z and P = V^2*Z also \$PF = \frac{RealPower}{AppPower} \$

Answer (score 2):

Given it is a homework question I'm not going to give you a full answer, and you haven't shown any working or attempt, so I'll be even more vague. But you do have enough information to work out what input voltage is.

- You know the real power and power factor of the load, so you can work out the apparent power (real+reactive) into the load.
- You also know the voltage across the load (hint: you should know how to find peak from RMS) so knowing the apparent power you can work out the impedance of it.
- Once you know the impedance you can work out the current.
- Once you know the current you can work out the voltage across the wire impedance.
- Once you know the voltage across the wire impedance you can work out the input voltage.

Comment: A full answer is not what I wanted, as I just wanted a direction. Thanks for pointing things out. I'll try to solve it now.